# Tween camera.position back to original position three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, tween.js

Hello I am trying to reset/tween the camera back to it's original position the camera is tweening but the result isn't as expected you can see the problem in this pen: 
https://codepen.io/uiunicorn/pen/mdeKoLm

code I am using to try and tween the camera back to it's starting/original position:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", function() {
     console.log('entered doc');
     }).on("mouseleave", function() {
        // set camera back to this: camera.position.set(-10, 90, 8.7);
        var tweenCam = new TWEEN.Tween(camera.position)
                .to({
                    x: -10,
                    y: 90,
                    z: 8.7
                }, 500).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut) // relative animation

                .onComplete(function() {

                })
                .start();
    });
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: "the result isn't as expected"... well, what is the expected result? You're telling the camera to go all the way up to `y:90`, and that's what it's doing.

Comment: @Marquizzo if you look at my codepen the cameras starting point is y:90 and y doesn't change so why is it tweening from 0 to 90 when the cameras y axis is set to 90 and doesn't change

Comment: You've got conflicting instructions because setting `camera.position` gets overridden by `OrbitControls` and its rotation around the target. Are you sure that instead of `TWEEN.Tween(camera.position)` you don't want to do `TWEEN.Tween(controls.target)`?

Comment: @Marquizzo thanks for pointing out the controls I forgot about that I have removed it and I have set the camera and tween to 0,0,0 but now it has a zoom in kind of effect https://codepen.io/uiunicorn/pen/abvjNrQ any idea's?